# Having trouble closing and reopening of communication port RS232

Tags: c#, serial-port, port

I'm trying to get the weight attached to a computer using RS232 com port.

I can read the weighing, but when I walk out the form , and came again -

My program and computer freezing.

this is my code:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    port.DataReceived += new s system.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Recepcion);

    if (port.IsOpen == false)
    {
      try
      {
         port.Open();
      }
      catch (Exception oex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(oex.ToString());
      }
    }
}


private void Actualizar(object s, EventArgs e)
{
   //I try this
   lblMSG.Text = ExtractDecimalFromString(port.ReadLine()).ToString();
   port.DiscardInBuffer();

   //Also I try this
   lblMSG.Text = ExtractDecimalFromString(port.ReadExisting()).ToString();
   port.DiscardInBuffer();
}


private void Recepcion(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Actualizar));
  }
  catch { }
}
```

and when i close the form i do this:

```
 port.DataReceived -= new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Recepcion);

GC.Collect();   //also i try to remark this
port.Close();
port.Dispose();
this.Close();
```

It is not always freezes, sometime yes...sometime no....

I searched the entire network still does not answer and solution.

I'm really  despair. I wish to find a solution here

Comment: What's so complicated ?  There's no solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an external usb-serial adapter (instead of COM1) to exclude hardware issues?

Shouldn't GC.Collect() be ran after port.Close() and port.Dispose().

Which code line causes the freeze?

Comment: i work with USB to COM cable. i mark this like: GC.Collect();  , the freeze causes in  port.Close();

Comment: Have you found any solution to your problem yet? Have you tried on another computer? Maybe it's caused if you doing the close operation from the UI thread...